# Error in graphQL python example code

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I am starting working on GraphQL and as I am from python background I am using GraphQL with Python. 
I followed the steps provided here [Link](http://graphql.org/code/#graphene-http-graphene-python-org-github-https-github-com-graphql-python-graphene) but I am still facing issues.

```
An error occurred while resolving field Query.hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/graphql/execution/executor.py", line 311, in resolve_or_error
    return executor.execute(resolve_fn, source, info, **args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/graphql/execution/executors/sync.py", line 7, in execute
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: resolve_hello() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'context' and 'info'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/graphql/execution/executor.py", line 330, in complete_value_catching_error
    exe_context, return_type, field_asts, info, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/graphql/execution/executor.py", line 383, in complete_value
    raise GraphQLLocatedError(field_asts, original_error=result)
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: resolve_hello() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'context' and 'info'
None
```

Please, help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving much information here, maybe the code that triggers the error would be helpful, but googling I found some related posts

https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/601

https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/282

Maybe check the versions that you are using as they mention on the first link

Comment: I think I provided the complete information. I added a link which corresponds to the details I have implemented.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the graphQL documentation is out of date.  Graphene-python 2 changed the method signature.  Try something like this instead

```
def resolve_hello(self, info, **kwargs):
    return 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Thanks, a ton it helped. and thanks for correcting my question also.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  I edited the question so that the next person who has this problem can find it.  You should accept the answer for the same reason (so that the solution is clear.)

Comment: I agree with what you are saying.. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try to like this one concept example on date:**

Graphql required positional arguments
**info**,and ****kwarg**

```
 def resolve_generated_date(self, info, **kwargs):
        created_date = self.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        return created_date
```